# API Whatsapp to send messages from an external application

Tags: api, whatsapp, whatsapi

I want to implement Whatsapp
to send information from an external application. The idea is to use this
external application to send information throughout Whatsapp.

If you can help me about the terms and
conditions and if this query is possible to develop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way through which you can send WhatsApp message from your self created application. Use this link [Chat API](https://chat-api.com/en/).

But it only provides 3 days trail period and after that you have to purchase it.

The process in that is, you have to register with your google account, then scan the QR code provided(which changes after every 45 seconds). and you are set to go, they will provide you the API for : PHP, Node.JS, Jquery, CURL.

One thing more you always have to keep your phone connected with the internet everytime.

Also I found a drawback in that, i.e. they also provide API to read messages, but it is too slow, as in my condition I can see my messages of yesterday but not of today.